# packaging and uploading visual webparts in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I m creating a visual webpart in SharePoint 2010 and I want to package it and upload in site other than the one it was validated for. How to do it?

Thanks
Anoop George Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project directory is `C:\projects\yourwebpart`

Go to `C:\projects\yourwebpart\bin\Debug`

There should be a `wsp` file in that directory.

Copy the `wsp` to your target server

Install the wsp (`stsadm -o addsolution` or `powershell Add-SPSolution`)

**EDIT**

http://patrickboom.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/using-powershell-to-deploy-sharepoint-solutions-wsp-2/

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/12/02/adding-and-deploying-solutions-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: can please give me the steps to install wsp in target server

Comment: Let me explain my requirement clearly.. I have to create the visual web part and send it to another vendor to integrate it at their server as a part of their farm.But I do not want to disclose the code to them... Is it possible?

Comment: you have to send the vendor 'something', whether it is obfusticated or not, they will most likely be able to reverse engineer anything you send

Comment: how to integrate it their server? in the case of webpart we can send the wsp files to them and get it uploaded at the server.. but how to do the same for visual web parts?

Comment: visual web parts should package the ascx into the wsp if you build it in vs2010.